# Setting up the shell environment on Remote SSH connection in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'd like to use VSCode's Remote--SSH feature on a cluster here. However, when one logs in, the cluster is not suitable for development. One must source a script or two to configure the shell first.

How can I get VSCode to do this?

I don't want to put the script in each command I have in the tasks.json, etc., nor does it belong in my .bashrc (or similar) file. I wasn't able to figure out anything from the documentation. Many thanks, in advance!

P.S. There may be a non-remoting setting that allows you to do this, but I didn't find that either.